# Receiving "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error when inserting a large amount of data into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a large amount of content from a field into a MySQL database and I am getting an error when the content is too large. To reproduce the bug, I have created a test table with the problem field `LONGBLOB`

Here is the code:

```
$c = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

$content = '';
for ($i=0; $i<1048511; $i++) $content .= 'A';

$sql = '
    INSERT
    INTO `bg`.`test` (`content`)
    VALUES ("' . $content . '")
';

$r = mysql_query($sql, $c);
```

The error message:

```
E_NOTICE
mysql_query(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

The request is accepted if there is one less iteration in the for loop  ($i < 1048510).

Comment: Your for() loop is utterly pointless:  `$content = str_repeat('A' 1048511);` will do just as well, and you're probably exceeding mysql's max_allowed_packet anyways.

Comment: In my.ini :

    [wampmysqld]
    port  = 3306
    socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock
    key_buffer = 16M
    max_allowed_packet = 16M
    
    [mysqldump]
    quick
    max_allowed_packet = 16M

Comment: add `set_time_limit(0);` above the loop. And please, learn to avoid mysql-commands, use PBO instead, see [link](http://no2.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Default 1048576

You are probably exceeding your max allowed packet